# Memory management problem in GTMTest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Hello
I have a problem with the following code in a GTMTestCase:

```
- (void)testSomething {
myType *year = [myType valueFromString:@"1978"];
STAssertTrue([year isKindOfClass:[XBNumberAttribute class]], @"Must be subtype.");
}
```

If I build this (=execute the tests), I get a "segmentation fault "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$EXECUTABLE_PATH" -RegisterForSystemEvents, Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 139 " error. This however goes away as soon as I retain the year object (which is actually autoreleased in the valueFromString method, see below):

```
- (void)testSomething {
myType *year = [[myType valueFromString:@"1978"] retain];
    //STAssertTrue(([year retainCount] == 2), @"Retain count wrong");
STAssertTrue([year isKindOfClass:[XBNumberAttribute class]], @"Must be subtype.");
}
```

Uncommenting the retainCount assertion indeed shows that the retain count is 2 at this point. However, if I put [year release] at the end of the method, the build fails again with the same error as explained above.

What is the matter here?

For the sake of completeness I include the code of valueFromString:

```
+ (id)valueFromString:(NSString *)pString { 
return [[[myType alloc] initWithString:pString] autorelease];
}
```

And here the initWithString method:

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)pString  {
if (self = [super initWithString:pString]){ 
}
return self;
}
```

pointing to the following super type method:

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)pString 
{
if (self = [super init]) {
theNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[pString intValue]];
}
 return self;
}
```

Comment: when you do return [[[myType alloc] you already retain the value.. So if you do both alloc and retain, you would retain it twice..

Comment: Show us the code for `initWithString:`

Comment: I included the initWithString code. Do you see any problem there? @stackr: that's exactly why I wonder why this works only IF I use retain, but not if I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching on all the autorelease debug options (see http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/87251-how-do-debug-an-autorelease-crash.html), I found the solution:

The variable theNumber is not accessed via the property accessor, so it is not actually retained (in the initWithString of the super type method, last code snippet). As it is however receiving a release in this type's dealloc method because it is marked as a @property (retain) (information not included here, but important!), I got an error when the autorelease of the child object was called (first code snippet): it released the supertype and with it the attribute which was not there anymore.